# Trying to access Action method in Area for Kendo Combobox datasource

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So my combobox is not hitting my method in my Area/Controller. Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group" id="assets_group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LinkedPACIds, "Add a PAC:")
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("ramt_linked_pac_combobox")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .Placeholder("Select PAC...")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
        .Filter("contains")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .MinLength(1)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Custom()
            .ServerFiltering(false)
            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
            .Transport(transport => transport
            .Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("Linked PACS", "GetLinkedPACs", "RAMT", new { Area = "RAMT"});
            }));
        })

    )
</div>
```

I tried adding my area as an attribute at the end, but it will not hit my controller method. How do I hit my action method in the controller of my specified RAMT area?

Comment: You have auto-bind as false so the datasource won't read until you interact with the dropdown part of the combobox. Does the controller method hit when you do that or not?

Comment: Thank you for this.... I did not realize AutoBind did that.